# Why doesn't the break statement work in this program?

Tags: python, loops

My program is supposed to tell users how many months it will take to double the money in their investment account. I am able to do the calculations correctly, but I'm unable to break out of the loop and print the statement that tells the user the final sentence "It will take x months to double your investment with a y% return".

```
balance = int(input("Enter an initial Roth IRA deposit amount:"))
apr = int(input("Enter an annual percent rate of return:"))

month = 0

while balance != 2*balance:
    added_interest = balance * (apr / 100) / 12
    balance = balance + added_interest
    month +=1
    formatted_balance = "${:.2f}".format(balance)
    print("Value after month", month,":", formatted_balance)
    if balance == 2*balance:
        break
print("It will take", month, "months to double your investment with a", apr, "% return")
```

Comment: `if balance == 2*balance:` Is this really what you want? It is true if and only if `balance == 0`.

Comment: How precisely do you expect a variable to be twice its own value? The only time that would apply is with `0` (or weirdo `float` values like `NaN`, `inf`, `-inf`, etc.). For any non-zero integer, it's definitionally false. Perhaps you might considering saving off `2 * balance` to another variable before the loop begins, so you know what it will actually be? Also, you definitely want to test for `>= double_initial_balance`, not `==`; `float` math is too imprecise, and you're basically guaranteed to never hit *exactly* double the initial balance even with carefully chosen rates of return.

Comment: You are using `balance == 2*balance`, which will always evaluate to `false`. So the code does not break. You must use a different variable (I would name it `newBalance`) to store the updated balance. Additionally, you are breaking only when `newBalance == 2*balance`, but newBalance can be larger than 2*balance. So try using `newBalance >= 2*balance`.

Comment: The `if` is not required, because the `while` does the same test (but wrongly, see the other comments)

Comment: @kamoney: You're welcome. I expanded that comment to a full answer; if it solves your problem, please click the check box to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that testing `balance` against `2*balance` is always testing the *current* balance, not double the *initial* balance. Just store off the computed doubled balance initially, and test if the current balance is still less than that (no need for separate `if`/`break`, your `while` condition will handle it):

```
balance = int(input("Enter an initial Roth IRA deposit amount:"))
apr = int(input("Enter an annual percent rate of return:"))

month = 0

doubled_balance = 2 * balance  # Store off doubled initial balance

while balance < doubled_balance:  # Check current balance against doubled initial,
                                  # and use <, not !=, so you stop when you exceed it,
                                  # not just when you're exactly equal
    added_interest = balance * (apr / 100) / 12
    balance = balance + added_interest
    month +=1
    formatted_balance = "${:.2f}".format(balance)
    print("Value after month", month,":", formatted_balance)
    # No need for if/break
print("It will take", month, "months to double your investment with a", apr, "% return")
```

All that said, this doesn't need a loop at all. The initial balance doesn't matter (it takes just as long to double $1 as to double $1000 with a fixed rate of return, ignoring rounding errors), so this reduces to a simple conversion for APR to APY to account for monthly compounding, followed by a logarithm computation to figure out what power of the APY is necessary to reach 2 (a doubling), then convert from months to years and round up (since you won't double until the end of that month):

```
import math

apr = int(input("Enter an annual percent rate of return:"))
apr_decimal = apr / 100
apy = (1 + (apr_decimal / 12)) ** 12 # Standard APR to APY computation for monthly compounding
months = math.ceil(math.log(2, apy) * 12)  # Compute the power (years) of APY to double the investment
                                           # then multiply by 12 and round up to a full month
print("It will take", months, "months to double your investment with a", apr, "% return")
```

Comment: I was thinking of storing the *incremented* balance but both work the same I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

In your comparison you compared `balance` with `2*balance`. Obviously `balance == 2*balance` will always be `false`, if `balance > 0`. So your code is stuck there forever if someone plans to invest anything more than $0.

You need a new variable to store the updated balance with rate of return:

```
# assuming you have balance and apr set
newBalance = balance  # balance + returned amount

month = 0

while newBalance < 2*balance:
    # replace ! with <, so that loop breaks when newBalance >= 2*balance
    added_interest = newBalance * (apr / 100) / 12
    newBalance = newBalance + added_interest
    month +=1
    formatted_balance = "${:.2f}".format(newBalance)
    print("Value after month", month,":", formatted_balance)
```

The code above assumes that the added interest is calculated based on `newBalance` value. Please tell me if this does not work for you. I will debug it later.

Comment: Your code will mess up calculations . it wont actually precisely calculate double balance months

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin depends if it is simple or compound interest. I'll edit this.

Comment: thank you, both you and ShadowRanger helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little bit simpler solution.

```
from math import log, ceil

apr = int(input("Enter an annual percent rate of return: "))
rate = apr/12/100 # monthly rate

months = ceil(log(2)/rate)

print("It will take", months, "months to double your investment with a", apr, "% return")
```

prints:

```
Enter an annual percent rate of return: 10
It will take 84 months to double your investment with a 10 % return
```

This was calculated using the formula for continuous compounding. With a FV (future value) = PV (present value) * e**(rate * periods).

```
FV = PV * e**(rate*periods)
FV/PV = e**(rate*periods)
log(FV/PV) = log(e**(rate*periods))
log(FV/PV) = (rate*periods) * log(e)
log(FV/PV) = (rate*periods) * 1
log(FV/PV)/rate = periods
```

Since you want to find the months to double your initial investment, FV/PV will equal 2, so:

```
log(2)/rate = periods. (The log(e) == 1 above)
```

`e` and compound interest is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).